# named scope based on number of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, group-by, has-many-through, record-count

I am doing some basic sql logic and I want to use a named scope.  I'm trying to find out how many members of a season have also participated in another season (i.e. they are returning members).

```
class Season
  has_many :season_members
  has_many :users, :through => :season_members

  def returning_members
    users.select { |u| u.season_members.count > 1 }
  end
end

class SeasonMember
  belongs_to :season
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :season_members
end
```

Is it possible to use :group and friends to rewrite the returning_members method as a scope?

I happen to be using Rails 2.3 but I'll also accept solutions that rely on newer versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you really want to put this scope on Season, since that would imply that you are looking for Seasons which have repeat users.  But, I assume you want Users that have repeat seasons.  With that assumption, your scope would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 scope :repeat_members, 
    :select=>"users.*, count(season_members.season_id) as season_counter",
    :joins=>"JOIN season_members ON season_members.user_id = users.id",
    :group=>"users.id",
    :having=>"season_counter > 1"
end
```

which would result in the following query:

```
 SELECT users.*, count(season_members.season_id) as season_counter FROM "users" JOIN season_members ON season_members.user_id = users.id GROUP BY users.id HAVING season_counter > 1
```

Confirmed with: Rails 3.1.3 and SQLite3

Comment: Ah, I see.  Glad i could help. I definitely agree with getting that sql out of the code with joins(), but for the example, i figured i'd leave it in there for consistency since the other keys were pretty sql dependent. :-) -md